# Is there a way to optimize theis mysql statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

This mysql is what I have on my site now, but I would like to know if there is a way I can make it better

```
    SELECT unique_id FROM 
(SELECT unique_id,price FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10) AS R
    ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I can't really run a test without having some test data. I'm assuming unique_id is the primary key for your table

Comment: there is an id field that is a primary key, auto increment and unique_id which is an md5 hash of the username

Comment: wait, so which field is the auto_increment and primary key? It has to be `id` right? and then `unique_id` is the md5() has of the user's name

Comment: Whats the purpose of this query? You fetch 10 random rows, then you sort thous 10 and take the only one with highest price?

Comment: to give some weight to the returned result. I want the higher priced items to show up more often, but not return the highest price item every time